# SQOOP IMPORT/EXPORT null values on/to HIVE Database

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

From different use cases I have understood the difference between `--input-null-non-string` VS `--null-non-string` and `--input-null-string` VS `--null-string` parameters.
The definition in [the SQOOP documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_5) left me some uncertainty

> Sqoop will by default import NULL values as string null. Hive is
>   however using string \N to denote NULL values and therefore predicates
>   dealing with NULL (like IS NULL) will not work correctly. You should
>   append parameters --null-string and --null-non-string in case of
>   import job or --input-null-string and --input-null-non-string in case
>   of an export job if you wish to properly preserve NULL values. Because
>   sqoop is using those parameters in generated code, you need to
>   properly escape value \N to \N:

I try to recap the result of what I tried and verified, in 2 simply bullets.

- `--input-null-*` parameters: obviously their principal aim is to manage the NULL values on HIVE (or any other RDBMS), which use by default \N for NULL values. These parameters have to be used where you are using HIVE (by HIVE side). When you EXPORT from HIVE to MySQL they are required to map NULL values.
- `--null-*` parameters: they are used by MySQL's side. Thus, for example when you IMPORT or EXPORT from/to MySQL.

Comment: input-null-string & input-null-non-string -> used when we are exporting to another RDBMS server.

null-string & null-non-string -> used when we are importing

please test the above on a sqoop command you will then have a clear understanding..

Comment: Thanks for the generalization, obviously HIVE is not the only RDBMS used.
About --null-string & --null-non-string they are available also in export
`   --null-non-string <null-str>          Null non-string representation
   --null-string <null-str>              Null string representation`
From sqoop export --help.